# How to capture logs in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write the script where I need to copy one folder from server on multiple servers (100) and same time When I run this batch file I want log file that on how many servers copy successfully completed with date & time.

I am able to copy the folder from one server to other using xcopy command but need help in capturing results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time /T
```

Will print the current time to the output stream

The easiest thing to do is to just capture all of the output from your batch file execution to a file. To do this, just use a command of the form:

```
MyBatchfile.Bat > Logfile.txt 2>&1
```

to pipe both stdout and stderr to a file.

Comment: @@ Stephen thanks for the response however I am new to this batch file scripting so unable to test given output however I am going to copy paste my script below and then please add/remove anything require